# Convergence in compact-open topology on the Sierpiński space

Tags: gn.general-topology, limits-and-convergence

**Question:**
Equip $\{0,1\}$ with the [Sierpiński topology $\{\{1\},\{0,1\},\emptyset\}$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Sierpinski+space), let $X$ be a compact metric space, and equip $C(X,\{0,1\})$ with the compact-open topology.  Let $\{B_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of open subsets of $X$ and $B$ also be open in $X$.  Concretely, what does it mean for $I_{B_n}$ converges to $I_B$ in this (compact-open) sense?

**Answer?:**
Am I correct in understanding that this means, for every compact subset $K\subseteq B$, there is some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K\subseteq B_{N}$?

*Or am I overlooking something?*

Comment: What is $I_B$? Is it not just $B$? Is you space Hausdorff?

Comment: Do you realize that by writing $N_K$ instead of just $N$ you are needlesly bringing in the axiom of choice? Just say "for every compact $K \subseteq B$ there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K \subseteq B_N$". (I am saying this because you used the tag `constructive-mathematics` so maybe you care.)

Comment: Since $X$ is locally compact the compact-open topology on $C(X,\mathbb{S})$ coincides with the Scott topology induced by the pointwise ordering. For this reason its basically never going to be Hausdorff (in any case $\mathbb{S}$ is a retract of $C(X,\mathbb{S})$ whenever $X$ is nonempty). I don't think sequences are particular useful here.

Comment: Another way to go is to identify $C(X,\mathbb{S})$ with the set of *closed* subsets $CL(X)$ of $X$. Then the compact-open topology becomes the cocompact topology, and because of $X$ agrees with the upper-Kuratoski topology. This is the topology determined by the following convergence structure: a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $CL(X)$ upper-Kuratowski converges to $A_0$ if $\bigcap_{F\in\mathcal{F}}cl(\bigcup_{A\in F}A)\subseteq A_0$. People have spent some time writing about this stuff, so it might be useful to you to check out some of their papers.

Comment: @Tyrone Doesn't the Upper-Kurtatowksi convergence coincides with the set-theoretic limit superior if each $A \in F$ is compact?  Or have I missed something?

Comment: Are you taking the closure operator which appears in the middle into account?

Comment: Right; since $F$ may be infinite.  Can I ask you (to help gel ideas in my head) for a simple example where the two differ; say in the case where $X=[0,1]$?  I would really appreciate it :)  (say we consider the upper-Kuratowski limit of a sequence; to make things even more familiar)

Comment: Are you familiar with Gerald Beer's Book *Topologies on Closed and Convex Sets*? He discusses the upper-, lower-, and Kuratowski convergences in $\S5.2$. You might like to spend some time with it. He gives a characterisation of sequential convergence in Le.5.2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answer is not correct. Let Y the space $\{0,1\}$ with the Sierpinsky-topology. The compact-open topology is generated by the set of $T(K,U) := \{f \in C(X,Y) \colon f(K) \subset U\}$ with $K \in \mathcal{K}(X)$ (compact subsets) and $U$ open in $Y$. W.l.o.g. $U = \{1\}$. Since $C(X,Y) = \{1_B \colon B \text{ open in } X\}$ ($1_B$ the indicator function) we get $T(K,\{1\}) = \{1_B \colon K \subset B, B \text{ open }\}$. It follows that $\{T(K,\{1\}) \colon K \in \mathcal{K}(X)\}$ is a base (not only a subbase) for the compact-open topology.

Now $1_{B_n} \to 1_B$ (for an arbitrary net) is equivalent to $1_{B_n} \in T(K,\{1\})$ finally in $T(K,\{1\})$ for each (neighbourhood) $T(K,\{1\})$ of $1_B$, i.e. $K \subset B_n$ finally for each $K \subset B$. For an (arbitrary) counterexample let $X = [0,1]$, $B = [0,1/2)$ and $B_n = \emptyset$ if $n$ is uneven and $B_n = [0,1/2-1/n)$ if $n$ is even.