# Relationship between Hausdorff convergence of sets and indicator functions

Tags: gn.general-topology, limits-and-convergence, metric-spaces, set-valued-analysis

Let $\{K_n\}_n$ be a sequence of compact subsets of a metric space $X$, and $K\subset X$ be compact.  If $K_n$ Hausdorff converges to $K$, i.e.:
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} d_{\mathrm H}(K_n,K) = \max\left\{\,\sup_{x \in K_n} d(x,K),\, \sup_{y \in K} d(K_n,y) \,\right\} = 0
,
$$
then what can be said of the convergence of $I_{K_n}$ to $I_K$?

**What I know:**
Indeed, since Hausdorff convergence strictly implies convergence of the upper Kuratowski limits then, by [Convergence in compact-open topology on the Sierpiński space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382810), we know that $I_{K_n}$ converges to $I_K$ in $C(X,\{0,1\})$ for the compact-open topology if $\{0,1\}$ has the [Sierpiński topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space).

**What I expect:**  Since the Hausdorff topology is strictly finer than the Sierpiński topology then, is there a topology $\tau$ on $C(X,\{0,1\})$ for which:
$$
I_{X-K_n} \overset{\tau}{\to} I_{X-K} \Leftrightarrow K_n \overset{d_H}{\to} K.
$$

Comment: Note that if you use the functions $D_K(x):=\text{dist(x,K)}$ in place of $I_K(x)$, then the uniform norm $\|D_K-D_L\|_\infty$ *is* the Hausdorff distance $d_H(K,L)$

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks, actually, I did notice this, but I'm not sure how this would translate to indicator functions.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. According to the linked post, the Sierpinski topology is $\{ \emptyset, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0, 1 \} \}$. Wouldn't this mean that $\mathbf{1}_K$ is not actually continuous when $K$ is compact? (The preimage $\mathbf{1}_K^{-1}(\{ 0 \}) = X \setminus K$ is not closed, if $X$ is connected for example.)

Comment: @LeoMoos Yes, the identification is with $X-K_n$ and $X-K$.  Thanks for noticing the typo :)

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, but I was looking for a metric directly on $C(X,\{0,1\})$ with a "intrinsic meaning"; in the sense that I shouldn't push-forward+pull-back via the homomorphism $C(X,\{0,1\})-> Comp(X)$.  You know?

Comment: @LeoMoos I gave your comment some more though.  Since the topologies $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$ and $\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{0,1\}\}$ are homeomorphic, then choosing the latter means that $\boldsymbol 1_K$ is continuous iff K is closed.